# Inserting one document in elasticsearch by using logstash

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

> ```
> Doing data migration from mongodb to elasticsearch . I am using logstash tool with jdbc connectivity.
>
> conf file
>
> input {
>   jdbc{
>     # NOT THIS # jdbc_driver_class => "Java::mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"
>   jdbc_driver_class => "Java::com.dbschema.MongoJdbcDriver"
>     jdbc_driver_library => "D:/ELK/jarfile/mongojdbc3.0.jar"
>     jdbc_user => "******" #no user and pwd
>     jdbc_password => "*****"
>   # use_column_value => true
>   # tracking_column => "%{[application_id]}"
>     jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mongodb://username:password@mongodb.sandboxforbank.com:27017/Feature-QA-4?ssl=true"
>   # jdbc_connection_string => ""
>     statement => "             
>                                       db.oaoapplicants.aggregate([
>     {
>         $match: {
>             _applicationStatus: 'ACTIVE',
>           'application_id' : 'DB2021012131408'
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         '$lookup': {
>             'from': 'oaoproductdetails',
>             let: {
>                 product_code: '$product_code'
>             },
>             pipeline: [
>                 {
>                     $match: {
>                         $expr: {
>                             $and: [
>                                 {
>                                     $eq: [
>                                         '$product_code',
>                                         '$$product_code'
>                                     ]
>                                 }
>                             ]
>                         }
>                     }
>                 },
>                 {
>                     $project: {
>                         _id: 0
>                     }
>                 }
>             ],
>             'as': 'productDetails'
>         }
>     },
>   {
>     $unwind : {
>        path : '$productDetails',
>        preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
>     }
>   },
>     {
>         '$lookup': {
>             'from': 'applicationtasksconfigs',
>             let: {
>                 application_id: '$application_id'
>             },
>             pipeline: [
>                 {
>                     $match: {
>                         $expr: {
>                             $and: [
>                                 {
>                                     $eq: [
>                                         '$application_id',
>                                         '$$application_id'
>                                     ]
>                                 },
>                                 {
>                                     $ne: [
>                                         '$assignedTo.username',
>                                         'Unassigned'
>                                     ]
>                                 },
>                                 {
>                                     $eq: [
>                                         '$deleted',
>                                         false
>                                     ]
>                                 }
>                             ]
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }, {
>                     $project: {
>                         _id: 0,
>                       'operationalLevelAgreement.overall._id':0,
>                       'operationalLevelAgreement.queued._id':0,
>                       'operationalLevelAgreement.assigned._id':0,
>                     }
>                 }
>             ],
>             'as': 'task'
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         $unwind :{
>             path : '$task',
>             preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
>         } 
>       
>     },
>     {
>         $project: {
>              '_id': 0,
>               'application_id': '$application_id',
>              'am_accountNo': '$am_accountNo'
>            }
>     },
>   {
>     $limit : 5
>   }
> ])
>               "
>                 
>   }
> }
>
>
> output {
>    stdout {
>     codec => rubydebug 
>   }
>   elasticsearch {
>     hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
>     index => "abc_index"
>   document_id => "%{[document][application_id]}"
>   }
> }
>
>
> I have 200 document into oaoApplicants collection but it is inserting only one document . It is printing the same document into logstash server many times.
>
> output:
>
>
> [2021-02-15T15:00:09,853][INFO ][org.mongodb.driver.connection][main][7b6fbba1145daf3a86792435727a285c67083201636ac6aa4e6741feb0541faa]
> ```
>
> Closed connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:24197}] to
> mongodb.sandboxforbank.com:27017 because the pool has been closed.
> {
> "document" => {
> "am_accountNo" => "846176",
> "application_id" => "DB2021012131408"
> },
> "@version" => "1",
> "@timestamp" => 2021-02-15T09:30:09.685Z
> }
> {
> "document" => {
> "am_accountNo" => "846176",
> "application_id" => "DB2021012131408"
> },
> "@version" => "1",
> "@timestamp" => 2021-02-15T09:30:09.685Z
> }
> {
> "document" => {
> "am_accountNo" => "846176",
> "application_id" => "DB2021012131408"
> },
> "@version" => "1",
> "@timestamp" => 2021-02-15T09:30:09.686Z
> }
> {
> "document" => {
> "am_accountNo" => "846176",
> "application_id" => "DB2021012131408"
> },
> "@version" => "1",
> "@timestamp" => 2021-02-15T09:30:09.671Z
> }
> {
> "document" => {
> "am_accountNo" => "846176",
> "application_id" => "DB2021012131408"
> },
> "@version" => "1",
> "@timestamp" => 2021-02-15T09:30:09.686Z
> }

Comment: You are using setting the `document_id` to a fixed value, your `application_id` does not seems to change, it is always `DB2021012131408`, this will make elasticsearch to update the documents every time it receives an event from logstash with this id.

Comment: @leandrojmp I have executed the query and it is giving unique application_id for each record

Comment: Let me try to understand what is happening, the result of your query is 200 documents and logstash is ingesting only one document and updating it or it is ingesting the same document 200 times? If you have only one document, than the problem could be with the id of the document, if you have the same document 200 times, then the problem could be in your query, not in logstash. Can you update your question with the output of your mongo db query? Use the `stdout` output to get this.